# Extract text from doc and docx

Tags: php, linux, vps, docx, doc

I would like to know how can I read the contents of a doc or docx. I'm using a Linux VPS and PHP, but if there is a simpler solution using other language, please let me know, as long as it works under a linux webserver.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587216/how-can-i-convert-a-docx-document-to-html-using-php, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173246/parsing-and-generating-microsoft-office-2007-files-docx-xlsx-pptx and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php for potential solutions.

Answer (score 15):

This is a .DOCX solution only. For .DOC or .PDF you'll need to use something else like [pdf2text.php](http://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1) for PDF

```
function docx2text($filename) {
   return readZippedXML($filename, "word/document.xml");
 }

function readZippedXML($archiveFile, $dataFile) {
// Create new ZIP archive
$zip = new ZipArchive;

// Open received archive file
if (true === $zip->open($archiveFile)) {
    // If done, search for the data file in the archive
    if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
        // If found, read it to the string
        $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
        // Close archive file
        $zip->close();
        // Load XML from a string
        // Skip errors and warnings
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
        // Return data without XML formatting tags
        return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
    }
    $zip->close();
}

// In case of failure return empty string
return "";
}

echo docx2text("test.docx"); // Save this contents to file
```

Comment: id does not work with .doc extension.
it do not have word/document.xml instead it has _rels/.rels.xml

what to do is such case??????

Comment: You helped me a lot. I was thinking about how to count the number of words in docx in PHP. And I just didn't think about `strip_tags`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle carriage returns correctly. The word at the end of a paragraph is merged into the incoming word of the next paragraph. Seems like it needs something along the lines of:

`$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
$content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);`

proposed by "M Khalid Junaid" answer

Comment: I'v used $xml->formatOutput = true; before load xml and  it helped me for carriage return.

Answer (score 15):

Here i have added the solution to get the text from **.doc,.docx** word files

### [How to extract text from word file .doc,docx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-php/19503654#19503654)

### For .doc

```
private function read_doc() {
    $fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
    $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
    $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
    $outtext = "";
    foreach($lines as $thisline)
      {
        $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
        if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
          {
          } else {
            $outtext .= $thisline." ";
          }
      }
     $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
    return $outtext;
}
```

### For .docx

```
private function read_docx(){

        $striped_content = '';
        $content = '';

        $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

        if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

            $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }// end while

        zip_close($zip);

        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
        $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

        return $striped_content;
    }
```

Comment: hi i used this to open doc files but i only get random characters any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you .doc files are working fine. But .docx files are not working. I used the above code. Mime type of my .docx file is shows 'application/msword'. Am I missing anything to add?

Answer (score 7):

## **[Parse .docx, .odt, .doc and .rtf documents](https://github.com/LukeMadhanga/PHPDocumentParser)**

I wrote a library that parses the docx, odt and rtf documents based on answers here and elsewhere.

The major improvement I have made to the .docx and .odt parsing is the that the library processes the XML that describes the document and attempts to conform it to HTML tags, i.e. *em* and **strong** tags. This means that if you're using the library for a CMS, text formatting is not lost

You can get it [here](https://github.com/LukeMadhanga/PHPDocumentParser)

Comment: Awesome! Using this to be able to merge .doc and .docx in a PDF created with mPDF.

Comment: This single class performs better than the other libraries :)

Comment: can this library also get the images?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I can have a look for you

Comment: Thank you Luke.. I also posted on the github repo

Answer (score 6):

My solution is [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) for .doc and [docx2txt](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/) for .docx

Assuming a linux server that you control, download each one, extract then install. I installed each one system wide:

Antiword: `make global_install`
docx2txt: `make install`

Then to use these tools to extract the text into a string in php:

```
//for .doc
$text = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/antiword -w 0 ' . 
    escapeshellarg($docFilePath));

//for .docx
$text = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/docx2txt.pl ' . 
    escapeshellarg($docxFilePath) . ' -');
```

docx2txt requires perl

no_freedom's solution does extract text from docx files, but it can butcher whitespace.  Most files I tested had instances where words that should be separated had no space between them.  Not good when you want to full text search the documents you're processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ApachePOI](http://poi.apache.org). It works well for Java. I suppose you won't have any difficulties installing Java on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, Extract text using apache Tika, you can extract multiple type of file content like .doc/.docx and pdf and many other.

Answer (score 0):

I used docxtotxt to extract docx file content. My code is as follows:

```
if($extention == "docx")
{   
    $docxFilePath = "/var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/writers/filename.docx";
    $content = shell_exec('/var/www/vhosts/abc.com/httpdocs/docx2txt/docx2txt.pl     
    '.escapeshellarg($docxFilePath) . ' -');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I insert little improvements in doc to txt converter function

```
private function read_doc() {
    $line_array = array();
    $fileHandle = fopen( $this->filename, "r" );
    $line       = @fread( $fileHandle, filesize( $this->filename ) );
    $lines      = explode( chr( 0x0D ), $line );
    $outtext    = "";
    foreach ( $lines as $thisline ) {
        $pos = strpos( $thisline, chr( 0x00 ) );
        if (  $pos !== false )  {

        } else {
            $line_array[] = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/", "", $thisline );

        }
    }

    return implode("\n",$line_array);
}
```

Now it saves empty rows and txt file looks row by row .

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Apache Tika** as complete solution it provides REST API.

Another good library is [**RawText**](https://rawtext.ambar.cloud/), as it can do an OCR over images, and extract text from any doc. It's non-free, and it works over REST API.

The sample code extracting your file with RawText:

```
$result = $rawText->extract($your_file)
```