# can not read docx file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create code of upload resume as doc or docx file and get the content of uploaded resume in codeigniter. So here I have written code like :

```
function read_file_docx($filename)
{
    //echo $filename;exit;
    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

    $zip = zip_open($filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {           
        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;            

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    echo $content;
    //echo "<hr>";
    //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
function f_read()
{
    $filename = '/var/www/html/job_portal/uploads/resume/Nisarg.docx';

    //echo $filename;
    $content = $this->read_file_docx($filename);
    if($content !== false) {

        echo nl2br($content);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';
    }
}
```

When I call this f_read() it returns as blank.

Here I have load file **file** helper. So how can I solve it?

Comment: have a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I have checked it but I could not resolve my problem.

Comment: Just use the given code, the code of doc is different as compared to docx

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I have created simgple doc file and write content as **nisarg bhavsar** then its return number 19 when i print **$zip** and when i upload resume then it display as blank page.