# convert docx file to string in php

Tags: php, wordpress, docx

I am using answer of this question to convert docx to text file

[How to extract text from word file .doc,docx,.xlsx,.pptx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php)

but it returns false beacause value of $zip is 11.
as I undestood 11 means it can not open file.
I use a url like this as $filename.

```
http://saha.com/wp-content/uploads/2/4/7/2016/07/test.docx
```

Could be it wrong ?

I tested it local and it works correctly with same url but when I use in wordpress as plugin I get error .

Comment: PHP does have configuration options to block access to URLs by means of file handling functions.

Comment: @arkascha could you explain more? what should i do?

Comment: If you take a short look into the official documentation you will see the conditions required for different attempts to open a file by means of (for example) the `fopen()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php: "PHP will check to make sure that `allow_url_fopen()` is enabled" That is one of many PHP configuration options. Check it. It often is turned _off_ due to security issues.

Comment: @arkascha but i can't find same thing for zip_open

Comment: oh... why do you think that `zip_open()` can be given a URL as argument to load a _remote_ file? AFAIK you have to copy it and then open the local file...

Comment: @arkascha what does mean local here? Do you mean I should copy remote file in some place like wp_content and then use it?

Comment: Local does indeed mean the local file system (on the "server"). I am a bit surprised that you say you are able to use a URL with that function on your local system. I never heard of that, actually, but then again one never stops to learn :-) You will find many examples of how to copy and then open the file. But as said: if you can actually use that function with a URL as argument then that _would_ be very convenient...

Comment: @arkascha you are right. I should copy it first.plz add your answer so I will accept it.Thank you so much

Comment: I didn't really provide an answer. I only hinted and guessed :-) Have fun!