# How can I read .doc file and get particular words from it in php

Tags: php, phpoffice

I want to read a doc file and get some result from it.

for example:
If I have a file - file.doc

and it has something like

> Resume
>
> Name: john carter
>
> Address: USA
>
> I am working as a php developer

Then I want something like:

```
array(
'name' => john carter
'Address' => USA 
)
```

and also it reject additional info from it.

is it possible?

I have tried phpoffice but I can't get anything related my need.

We can get whole file data easily but I can't recognize whatever I want.

I need is similar like abbyy gives for image to text.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: why such negative vote without any answer or comment?

Answer (score 1):

PHP docx reader: Convert MS Word Docx files to text
This class can convert MS Word Docx files to text.

It can extract the files from compressed Microsoft Word file in docx format.

The class can parse the document XML file and extract the text that it contains.

Refreance from question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503654/5212418

Comment: You can find it here : http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7934-PHP-Convert-MS-Word-Docx-files-to-text.html

Comment: thanks for answer... but not helpful to me as it gives full text instead of separated data. so not upvoted.

Comment: ok can you please tell me what are you doing.Its better you convert doc to text and then serach with logic

Comment: You will check this : www.codeproject.com/Questions/411713/Convert-to-doc-file-to-plain-text

Comment: I have used this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php/19503654#19503654  and also you sugested that...I have to work a lot still. but ok thanks for your efforts