# How to load word document using AJAX

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load MS Word file by keeping the original formatting as it is. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What have you researched? I don't think it is possible unless you convert it to an image server side or using a JS library

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is not a free coding service. We can help, but it's your job to work on this in first place. [Put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) first, then ask with a clear explanation and [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if applicable.

Comment: Without any further information it is a possible duplicate of [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you can use google iframe to render docs and pdf in your web page here is fiddle 
[enter link description here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m3me3/26/)

Comment: Providing a jsfiddle with your question is ok, but you have to include all relevant information within your answer and not as link to an external site. And external site might go down, the link might become invalide, or it might not be reachable for other reasons. Beside that it does not look like it provides any additional informations to the already linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of doing so using [**PHP docx reader: Convert MS Word Docx files to text**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php).
to retrieve the text from a word document `server side`, using ajax request then render it the way you like to.