# How can i get the text from a word document with (.rtf) extension?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, rtf

I need to  extract the text from a word document (only the text) and transcript the text into a textarea.

Comment: Just do it. More seriously: what did you try? We won't do your job for you/for free, we help solving bugs.

Comment: Salty, but also true though, no offense meant... We help for bugs and specific technical matter, you can't just come and ask "how should I do from scratch": that is the purpose of Google. When you have absolutely no clue, you have to make a little bit of research on your own mate!

Comment: You are right, sincerly i've searched too a solution for my problem but i didn't find anything that would fit my project so i asked to this community.
I was just to lazy to make a correct formed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do if I were you!

I would use one of the following libs to read the RTF:

- https://github.com/iarna/rtf-to-html
- https://github.com/Novlr/rtf2html

I don't know which one is the best, so you have to test them a bit.
They both produce HTML code, with the style matching the original one.

I think you want to get read of that (you mentionned you just want the text), so I would get the generated HTML, I would set it in an hidden `div` and I would extract only the text with `innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

this may help. please try to search for answers before ask. may be a possible duplicate of [How to extract text from word file .doc,docx,.xlsx,.pptx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php)