# zzip not listed in phpinfo() and function zip_open() not found

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to read a docx file from php. For this I found the solution at [How to extract text from word file .doc,docx,.xlsx,.pptx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php) - Answer 1.

This library requires zzip. So I installed zzip using WHM (I did not restart the server) but still it is not listed in phpinfo() & I still get the error

`function zip_open() not found`

when i try to run the following code :

```
$zip = zip_open($this->filename);
```

Comment: _"I did not restart the server"_ - Why not try that then?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson : Yes I am going to do that, actually I just restarted Apache, thought that it would work but in vain

Comment: is it enabled in the php.ini ?

Comment: For future reference, _always_ try _everything_ you can yourself before posting a question. Asking here should be when you've exhausted all other options.

Comment: Actually I just restarted Apache, thought that it would work but in vain

Comment: @kuh-chan : Dear sir, how to check it in php.ini, do you know the parameter name ? I went through the php ini in editor but can't anything like zzip

Comment: wait a moment... which php version are you running?

Comment: @kuh-chan : sir am using PHP Version 5.6.40

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i restarted, still nothing's like zzip listed in phpinfo