# Reading .docx file that are stored in a database in php

Tags: php, docx

So I save .docx files in my database as mediumblob, when I want to show it, it looks like this:

```
PK!ߤ�lZ [Content_Types].xml
```

I already have a class that can read this, but that class needs a file and can't read from the database directly:

[How to extract text from word file .doc,docx,.xlsx,.pptx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php)

Is there a way to directly read  this from the database without needing to use file_put_contents();?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You could try to utilize the php temp or memory wrapper. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php