# Convert doc to txt

Tags: php, ms-word, doc

I'm on a Linux server and I need to convert MS Word 97-2003 .doc format to plain text .txt files using PHP

I already tried this solutions:

[How to extract text from word file .doc,docx,.xlsx,.pptx php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php)

[Extract text from doc and docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540886/extract-text-from-doc-and-docx)

But both are just working fine for .docx format.

The issue is when I convert files, I got scrap characters at the end of the text.
The length of the chars I don't need vary depending on the length of the file.
Also, it may happen that if the file is a bit long, it get truncated.

Is there any simple way to get this converted?

Comment: Well, as simple I mean without using external apps like Apache POI or other Java stuff or Antiword...

Comment: You'll always need a library for this because PHP natively doesn't support this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've lastly come to use the following solution, launching Antiword:

```
private function doc() {
    $file = escapeshellarg($this->filename);
    $text = `/usr/sbin/antiword -w 0 $file`;
    return html_entity_decode(utf8_encode(trim($text)));
}
```