# How to execute docx2txt shell script with Php?

Tags: php, shell, terminal, docx

I'm using **[docx2txt](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/#code)** to extract `.docx` contents.
I can achieve this by running the shell script in terminal.

below is the `Terminal` shell script,

```
 niveus@niveus:/var/www/docx2txt$ ./docx2txt.sh test.docx

 Text extracted from <test.docx> is available in <test.txt>.
```

But I want to run this script with php as well.

I tried this,

```
<?php

 $docxFilePath = "test.docx";
 echo  $content = shell_exec('./docx2txt.sh '.escapeshellarg($docxFilePath));

?>
```

and it **outputs** `Failed to extract text from !`

(both `docx2txt.sh` and `test.txt` are in the same folder `docx2txt`)

Comment: CAn you check this solution : It has hypen `-` at the end of command. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14348458/1218075

Comment: @Makesh i am not getting the desired result even after adding hypen `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the **permission**. After changing the *permission* of the **docx2txt** folder to **chmod 777** 
the following `php` code worked.

```
<?php

 $docxFilePath = "test.docx";
 echo  $content = shell_exec('./docx2txt.sh '.escapeshellarg($docxFilePath));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your folder permission using below command

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/docx2txt
```